# Website loading issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

My developer coded the home page coming soon template. before now it was working fine the site was loading up but now it keeps loading. 
I have created a screen cast video to clear the issue and share entire page code.
Here is the link [Screencast](http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cbiujQl4Ys)

Comment: share your code

Comment: http://templatesoul.com/ loads fine for me

Comment: its loading now.

Comment: So your problem is resolved?

Comment: next time press f12 and look at the console, reason could be that it's failing to load a resource, the console will tell you which.

Comment: Reduce the size of `pizza.png`. 9.7MB for one image!? --- Everything else loads in under 500ms.

Comment: Maybe you just have bad internet connection

Comment: This problem is since last 24 hours. my internet is working fine, I checked youtube by playing HD video.

Answer (score 2):

In Portfolio you have two images (res.png and pizza.png). Loading both of them require 7800ms. Your whole request is nearly 8700ms. (in my current environment/using my network connection). Those two images are 90% of your loading time.

You also have two resources that are required but not there:

- cp.png
- ff.png

Both of them being in that Portfolio folder.

[image: req_loading_time]

1. Loading time
2. Loading time for res.png
3. Loading time for pizza.png

Red lines are 404 http responses (Not Found).